# No staged files match any of provided globs

Tags: git

I am trying to push my project to heroku. I did `git init`, `git add .`, `git commit -am "update"`. Then I get

> husky > pre-commit (node v8.10.0) No staged files match any of
>   provided globs. On branch dev Your branch is up to date with
>   'origin/dev'.
>   nothing to commit, working tree clean

When I try `git push heroku master` I get

> error: src refspec master does not match any. error: failed to push
>   some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-bey-836.git'

How to solve it?

Comment: can you run `git remote -v` and `git status` ?

Comment: I had to remove .git folder first. Now fixed.

Comment: The first error has nothing to do with Git. The second one occurs because you built a repository with no `master` branch.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the cache，you can try to change your code as you like.Then git add.，Then git commit -m ... you can solve this problem.